# Calling a function that will hide a button from another class - swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, button

I'm trying to create an IMDB-ish movie application where when the user doesn't login and presses a Skip button, a Favorite (add a movie to favourites) button would dissappear.

The LandingViewController is where the Skip button is and the MovieTableViewCell is where all the data is presented.

What must I do so that the hide action will work inside the function? what's the logic behind this? what am I missing?

Kindly check the below comments in the code. thanks !

```
import UIKit

class LandingViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var skipButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func didTapSkip(_ sender: Any) {
    MovieTableViewCell().hideButton()
   }

import UIKit

class MovieTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var languageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var releaseYearLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var posterImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var favoriteButton: UIButton?




    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        favoriteButton?.isHidden = true  // works here for some reason
    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


    }

    func hideButton() {
        favoriteButton?.isHidden = true  // doesn't work and If I unwrap it, the app will crash, because it will find the buttton as NIL for some reason
        print("hidebutton") // the print works so the function works when the skip is pressed

    }
```

Comment: Well, where is `favoriteButton` set?

Comment: Apart from using a TableViewCell like this, which is questionable, in _didTapSkip()_ you're instantiating a cell and call hideButton(). Here, in fact, your new instance belongs to no one! It will get deallocated in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using NSUserDefaults

In LandingViewController

```
@IBAction func didTapSkip(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didSkip")
}
```

In MovieTableViewCell

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didSkip") {
        favoriteButton?.isHidden = true  
    } else {
        favoriteButton?.isHidden = false  
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked ! Thank you so much ! To understand the logic as well, by using UserDefaults u have bound a key to the didTapSkip action and then you used a simple if/else to call it. It only works inside the awakeFromNib function because "When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established." Am I right?

Comment: UserDefaults should be accessible at any point, once the key has been set then your if else statement should work